# Check if any tests raise a deprecation warning with pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am using pytest to run tests in a Python package, and I would like to know if any of the code that is executed as part of the tests is raising deprecation warnings (when all tests are passing). Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("error")
```

will turn (all) warnings into errors, which may help.

Alternatively, you can get a list of generated warnings with

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
    print(w)

#>>> [<warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x7fee80484f50>]
```

and then assert on that list.

Comment: Please note that this example is no longer valid as python2.7 since the DeprecationWarnings are filtered out by default

Answer (score 1):

Starting with pytest 3.1, warnings are automatically displayed at the end of the session: see https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html

Comment: `py.test -W error::UserWarning` as mentioned there.