# How to show warnings in py.test

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest, pytest-django

I just ran [`py.test`](http://pytest.org) on my code and got the following output:

```
================== 6 passed, 2 pytest-warnings in 40.79 seconds =======================
```

However, I cannot see what `py.test` would like to warn me about. How can I turn on warning output to the console?

`py.test --help` offers me the `--strict` flag:

> --strict              run pytest in strict mode, warnings become
>   errors.

However I just want to see the output, not make my tests fail.

I checked [pytest.org](https://pytest.org/latest/recwarn.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920576/check-if-any-tests-raise-a-deprecation-warning-with-pytest) but they are only concerned with asserting warnings in python, not showing warnings generated on the commandline.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In this case, pytest-warnings are warnings which were generated for pytest and/or it's plugins. These warnings were not generated for your code. In order to list them in the report, you will need to use option `-r w`. Here is portion of `py.test --help`:

```
-r chars              show extra test summary info as specified by chars (f)ailed,
                      (E)error, (s)skipped, (x)failed, (X)passed
                      (w)pytest-warnings (a)all.
```

This will allow to show warnings in the report (top portion of the record) will list which pytest plugins use deprecated arguments (in my case bellow):

```
...
================================ pytest-warning summary ================================ 
WI1 /Projects/.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_timeout.py:68 'pytest_runtest_protocol' hook uses deprecated __multicall__ argument
WI1 /Projects/.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_capturelog.py:171 'pytest_runtest_makereport' hook uses deprecated __multicall__ argument
...
```

Comment: Actually it's not true, that those are always warnings, which are not generated for ones code. I had an example, where I added an `__init__` constructor to my test class, which caused `py.test` not to be able to use the test. The warning was not shown to me, even with `--strict`, but your answer helped me to make `py.test` show the warning, of which the cause was still in my own code.