# pytest does not show logger records

Tags: python, flask, logging, pytest

pytest won't show me the logger records that occur during testing. Checked that logging is enabled in config and that level is `DEBUG`, added `log_cli = 1` to pytest.ini, still doesn't work.

It captures stdout and stderr just fine, so usual `print()`s are displayed.
Tried running with `-r a` as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363433/how-to-show-warnings-in-py-test), to no avail.

Added `caplog` to my test, `caplog.records` is `[]`.

I know that code gets to the log emission point (through the use of prints).

EDIT: minimal reproducible examples:

```py
class TestLogging:
    def test_logging(self):
        from app import logger
        logger.error("log test")  # nothing shows up
        print("print test")  # prints as expected
        assert False

    def test_caplog(self, caplog):
        from app import logger
        logger.error("log test")  # nothing shows up
        print(caplog.records)  # prints '[]'
        assert False
```

Running with
`FLASK_ENV=testing pipenv run pytest controller/tests/test_user_routes.py -k test_logging`
and
`FLASK_ENV=testing pipenv run pytest controller/tests/test_user_routes.py -k test_caplog`

EDIT2: settings and how logger is set up: https://pastebin.com/EG8g90m5

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: Working on it now.

Comment: The next mystery is your app module - can you provide a minimal example of that? If I just use a dummy app with an index, import via `from app import app` and access the logger via `app.logger.info(...)`, the live log is emitted just fine.

Comment: Do you use [`app.logger`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.logger) at all? Or do you configure the logger yourself?

Comment: @hoefling added pastebin with some details about app. FTR, logger itself work fine in development environment, I see log records in server logs.

Comment: Your example code works on my machine, logs are both captured and emitted live.

Comment: @hoefling but are they caught and displayed by the test? On my setup, they are emitted as well, I can see them in server logs on live run, pytest just does not display them.

Comment: Yes, both printed in the "live logs" section and captured via `caplog`.